# Get calendar data in WP7 as string

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to develop a pivot application for Windows Phone 7 using Visual Studio 2010. I got the data from the calendar with the following code.

```
void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext =
                from Appointment appt in e.Results
                where appt.IsAllDayEvent == false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                select appt;                
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            //No results
        }
    }
```

The problem comes when I tried to connect to the next button.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext.ToString() == "Meeting")
        {
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("http://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zNTMwNDYwX2hxRXZR/Crystallize.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);                
        }

        else
        {
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("https://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zMjAxODY0X0VBNDJY/Hetken%20tie%20on%20kevyt%20(piano%20cover)%20-%20YouTube.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);               
        }
        mediaElement1.Play();
```

How can I convert the data to string so that it can play the two songs correctly? Because right now, even though I set the event to "Meeting" on the calendar, it still plays the second song.

Answer (score 0):

You have binded the ListBox using the Appointment object, so the DataContext needs to be typecasted into the same. And by setting the event as Meeting if it means setting the Subject field of Appointment class as "Meeting" then this code should work fine.

```
if ((((Appointment)(AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext)).Subject).Equals("Meeting")))
    {
        mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("http://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zNTMwNDYwX2hxRXZR/Crystallize.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);                

    }
```

When you are doing AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext.ToString() you are converting the DataContext object's address value to string and not getting the required string value. Also "==" doesn't work for string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks but I tried the code and rebuilt the project and when I clicked on the second button, it just led to quitting the application instead of playing anything. May I know why?

Comment: When I tapped the button to play the songs on the phone, the entire program stopped and it quit the application. It gave no error during compilation.

Comment: if you run the program in debug mode it must break somewhere and throw some exception.